# Reuse of stored procedure results in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, query-performance

I'm working on read-replica of PostgreSQL database without possibility of creating any temporary tables (read-only transaction).

Consider I have stored procedure `foo(...)` which returns me `TABLE(...)` result (or `SETOF Foo_Type` which is the same).

This `Foo_Type` has some `type` field which defines type of data in the row.

In another procedure `foo_wrapper(...)` with fixed return type (it is also `TABLE(...)` or let's say `SETOF Foo_Wrapper_Type`) I need to do following:

depending on `Foo_Type.type` value I need merge results from `foo(...)` with different tables using `left join`. This is how it is done at the moment:

```
...
return query
select
   ft.*,
   a1.x1
   from foo(param1, param2, ...) ft
   left join a_table a on ...
   where ft.type = 'value_1'

union
select
   ft.*,
   b1.x1
   from foo(param1, param2, ...) ft
   left join b_table b on ...
   where ft.type = 'value_2'

...
```

There are dozens of this `union`-s.

Don't tell me about how evil and terrible designed my Schema is. I know it, it is legacy schema.

What I'm inquiring about is how to avoid multiple calling of `foo(...)` procedure in this statement?

This `foo_wrapper(...)` procedure works extremely slow. I suspect it is because of multiple calls of `foo(...)` procedure with same parameters and I'm not sure that DB caches its results inside one session.

So my question consists of 2 parts:

1. Is any way to "extract" and save results of `foo(...)` before my big union-select?
   `DECLARE results SETOF Foo_Type` doesn't work.
2. May be it is not the point for optimization and somebody can surely claim that results of first call of `foo(...)` are cached for further calls inside this procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a common table expression:

```
return query
with foo_data as (
  select * 
  from foo(param1, param2, ...)
)
select ft.*,
       a1.x1
from foo_data ft
  left join a_table a on ...
where ft.type = 'value_1'
union 
select ft.*,
       b1.x1
from foo_data ft
   left join b_table b on ...
where ft.type = 'value_2'
...
```

You probably want to use `union all` instead of `union`.

Comment: WOW, looks like a decision. I will check it tomorrow and my vote-up and check will not be delayed! Thank you!